# How can I prevent reverse voltage in my stop/tail light design?

Tags: reverse-polarity

I'm looking to modify the rear lights on my 72 VW beetle to enhance ascetics and improve safety.

I intend to use LEDs to achieve this and feel that both the indicators and reverse lights should be pretty simple circuits. Once I've figured out how many LEDs I need I can figure out the correct resistors required and wire them up in parallel.

I'm new to electronics so decided to find a testing platform and discovered Yenka which I've been using to try and figure out the more complex system I want for the stop/tail lights segment.

I decided I wanted an L shape illuminated when the car lights are on, then when the brakes are applied I want it to be one giant block. Due to the nature of the tail lights I have, to make things look neat I decided that when the brake lights are applied 2 LEDs from the tail lights would actually go off. (See picture)

[image: Example of desired results]

[image: Schematic made in Yenka]
[Click here to see large view schematic](http://i.imgbox.com/uMPfDwf4.png)

I've created the circuit in Yenka, I've figured out that I can use a relay to give the behaviour that I am after. I can turn the side lights on and off with no issue but when I come to the brake lights it's a different matter.

The lights turn on fine and all light up as I want, but when you turn the brake lights off it blows all the LEDs with an error message saying "Exploded Object - The peak reverse voltage was 178.91V. The maximum rating is 9V."

I've had a quick look into reverse voltage and know that a diode can be used to prevent it, which is why I have a diode separating the top 2 LEDs in the sidelight circuit to prevent them from getting power when the rest are illuminated.

The resisters are currently set to 350 ohms but haven't been calculated yet as I haven't worked out how many LEDs I'll actually use in my circuit.

Whats causing this reverse voltage? Why does it not affect the side lights in the same way? What causes the reading to be so high?

Please be patient with me if I ask stupid questions, and thanks for any help offered. I'm sure this is probably not the best solution or the most efficient.

Comment: A real circuit diagram would be far more useful than some random programs drawings. My best guess is that your relay is missing a freewheeling diode.

Comment: As I say I'm new to this, when I looked at the program it looked like I could build the circuit diagrams, which is what I have there.

If they aren't accurate/comprehensive enough I apologise but that's the best I can do atm.

Clicking on the relay to access its properties it states 12V Omron if that helps at all

Comment: Does your simulator assume some huge reactive load somewhere? Maybe from collapsing the field of the relay coil? Try putting a diode backwards across the relay coil or an RC suppressor on it to absorb transients.  Honestly, I think your simulator is just lieing to you.

Comment: Placing a diode across the relay does seem to have fixed the issue, and I assume thats what PlasmaHH meant when talking about a freewheeling diode.

Why does the diode fix the issue? I thought that if the switch for the brake light was open and no current was passing through then nothing would happen

Comment: FWIW, you should reconsider your design a bit; 12V is enough to put several diodes in series with a smaller resistor, saving power and components over your current solution.

Comment: NickJohnson I did think about running in series but felt, especially with the L shape tail light being so small, that should a component fail it would be safer to run parallel rather than potentially lose a third of my light

Comment: So will you build two versions of the lights so that the right hand side tail light and the left hand tail light have the "L" on the opposite sides?

Comment: That is the intention yes, I've got to figure out the quantity of LEDs per lamp and check to see how much power they consume to make sure it will work but I can't see it being any worse than standard bulbs

Comment: Please note that in many countries modifying the lighting system of a car can result in fines, or worse.

Comment: I live in the UK so there is no issue for me. As long as the lights function as they were designed and pass the UK MOT, checking road worthiness and safety it's all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one with no relays and no spikes, and [here's the LTspice circuit list](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kztlr5ksjnwmkxy/Brake%20and%20tail%20light.asc?dl=0) if you want to play with / simulate the circuit:

[image]

### TAIL LIGHT:

In operation, S1 is the tail light switch, shown on the simulator schematic as electrically operated, but in real life it's just the switch that turns on the tail lights.

When S1 and S2 are open, Q1 and Q2's bases are connected to GND through R1 ,R2, and R8, turning OFF Q1 and Q2, which will prevent current from flowing through the LED loads represented by R6 and R9 and illuminating them.

When S1 is made, however, Q1 and Q2's bases will be forward biased, which will turn them ON and illuminate the 13 LEDs comprising the 'L' shaped tail light.

Note that when S1 is made, D1 will be reverse-biased and will prevent the 12V on the output of S1 from affecting the brake light circuitry.

### BRAKE LIGHT

When S1 is open and S2 is made, D1 will be forward biased, which will turn on Q1,illuminating the 11 LEDs common to the tail light and the brake light.

Q2 would also be turned on by the current through R2 into its base, but the current through R3 turns ON Q3, which sinks the current that would otherwise flow into Q3's base to ground, preventing Q2 from turning on, which will keep the two tail light LEDs dark.

At the same time, current will flow through R4 into the base of Q4, illuminating the 15 LEDs which only turn on when the brake light switch is made.

If the tail lights are on when the brake pedal is pressed, all of the LEDs except for D4 and D5 will illuminate, and when the brake pedal is released D4 and D5 will come back on again, resulting in the 13 tail light LEDs being illuminated and the 15 brake light LEDs going dark.

Comment: I finally got back to this project and believe I have recreated your circuit more or less. 

http://imgbox.com/DS8Ssxx0 ---
http://imgbox.com/wpelklaq ---
http://imgbox.com/oEGqpyEj

Answer (score 0):

Why would there be a reverse voltage?  Surely, all this circuit is, is a battery driving a bunch of LEDs using a relay to switch in different configurations.

The only place in this circuit where you could possibly get a reverse voltage is across the relay coil as the magnetic field collapses, but that's not connected to the LEDs so the LED's aren't at risk here.  And you would deal with the reverse voltage (or back EMF as it's properly named) by connecting a diode (get the polarity right) across the relay coil.

Using a software tool to help in the design is a nice, but you stand a chance of the tool not reporting things (voltages, currents) correctly.

This is a simple DC circuit, you should be able to design this on paper and get it right.

Comment: I think had I attempted to draw this out on paper I would have looked at it and decided yeah that will work, then when it came time to build it I would likey have blown components. So for testing and learning it made my life much simpler.

Comment: You've got a lot of LEDs. Essentially you have two groups of LEDs, one group A, the second group B. And what you want to happen is: Tail lights - group A energised only. Brake lights - group A and B energised.  So design and build something with far fewer LEDs test it to ensure you've got the relay and switching logic right. The you can add more LEDs to each group in parallel with their own series resistors and increase the number of LEDs in to each group.  In this way you can build and test something of much lower complexity and if you blow a few LEDs it's not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Just to post an answer about why putting a freewheeling/flyback/reverse diode across the relay coil fixes your simulation problem:  The winding of a relay is a big coil.  When you energize it, power flows to pull the contacts closed.  When de-energized, the coil has stored energy that has to go somewhere.  By default, it will actually try to increase its voltage until it can discharge the energy.  A freewheeling diode gives that energy a safe path to dissipate.

Comment: "By default, it will actually try to increase its voltage until it can discharge the energy."  I don't like this statement.  Go back to basics, the relay is a coil and when energised there is a magnetic field. When you turn off the current, the magnetic field collapses and as it does so, by Faraday's Law of Induction, the changing magnetic field induces a voltage, that voltage in size is proportional to the rate of change of the magnetic field.  The idea that the voltage increases until it can discharge the energy isn't right.